# Upload multiple files for each entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine2 with symfony2.

This is my entity to upload the file.

First, it call the setFile() and put the path to $this->temp,

then,preUpload is called ,upload called.

It is OK for uploading onefile for each entity,however, I would like to upload multiple files for each entity.

How can I handle this ?

Do you have any samples for this purpose?

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path = "nophoto.jpeg";

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
private $file;

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */

public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
    $this->path = $this->getId().'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */

public function upload()

{
    if (null === $this->getFile1()) {return;}
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        // delete the old image
        unlink($this->temp);
        // clear the temp image path
        $this->temp = null;
    }
// you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
// so that the entity is not persisted to the database
// which the UploadedFile move() method does
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
        $this->getId().'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
    );
    $this->setFile(null);
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
    ? null
    : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->path;
}
public function getFile1()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
    ? null
    : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need new entity which will represent uploaded file with many-to-one (or many-to-many) association to your entity. This is most universal approach.

Alternatively you can store file names in array but that will complicate your validation and forms.

Comment: I see, I will try the universal way of any-to-one association. thanks very much